# After Wicket migration from 1.4.9 to 7.9.0 Wiquery 1.0.2 jar throwing error

Tags: wicket, wicket-7

I had migrated Wicket from 1.4.9 to 7.9.0. After these maven clean and install got success and when deploying in tomcat throwing below error.Please some one help me out. Is wiquery 1.0.2 jar supports the wicket 7.9.0.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter wicket.dpt
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.Application.setMetaData(Lorg/apache/wicket/MetaDataKey;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.odlabs.wiquery.core.commons.WiQueryInstantiationListener.<init>(WiQueryInstantiationListener.java:69)
    at org.odlabs.wiquery.core.commons.WiQueryInitializer.init(WiQueryInitializer.java:53)
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.initInitializers(Application.java:734)
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.initializeComponents(Application.java:642)
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.initApplication(Application.java:952)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:429)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5389)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

Comment: Why don't you use latest version? which will support wicket 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade Wiquery too:

```
org.wicketstuff:wiquery 7.x
```